# Incomplete types as function parameters and return values

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, return-type, incomplete-type

The following code [compiles successfully both with *clang++ 5.0.0* and *g++ 7.2*](https://godbolt.org/g/NdT26u) (with the `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -O0` compilation flags):

```
struct Foo;

struct Bar
{
    Foo get() const;

    void set(Foo);
};

struct Foo
{
};

Foo Bar::get() const
{
    return {};
}

void Bar::set(Foo)
{
}


int main()
{
    Bar bar{};

    (void)bar.get();
    bar.set(Foo{});
}
```

Is it valid to use incomplete types as function parameters and return values? What does the C++ say on it?

Comment: This is basically what you do in any header...

Comment: @Jaa-c It may sound silly but I have never used incomplete types as function return types or parameter types in my header files before.

Comment: The idea is that you don't make everyone who, possibly indirectly, includes your header *also* have to parse the full definitions of every type used by it, as they might not use functions that need said definitions. And if they *do*, then they can include the full definition themselves. I think debate rages wildly and forever whether it's good to expect that of your users, though. For headers used internally, I'd say it's a no-brainer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In a function *definition*, you cannot use incomplete types: [[dcl.fct]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.fct-12):

> The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition shall not be an incomplete (possibly *cv*-qualified) class type in the context of the function definition unless the function is deleted.

But a function *declaration* has no such restriction. By the time you define `Bar::get` and `Bar::set`, `Foo` is a complete type, so the program is fine.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it valid to use incomplete types as function parameters and return values? What does the C++ say on it?

In a function declaration, yes it is valid.

`[basic.def.odr]` lists situations where a type must be complete. There is no mention of function declarations in that list. Note that function definitions do need the definition for `T` for argument and return types of `T`.

Comment: Why is it problematic not to define the return type `T` in a header? The caller just has to add an `#include` for it, and in return for that very small inconvenience you reduce compile-time dependencies for everyone else, because not everyone who needs `fun.h` may actually call the function, especially if we are talking about a member function.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can use an incomplete type in the following ways:

1. As pointers;
2. As reference;

Because the declaration of the function doesn't create any object, so it is legal.