# I have two classes that need to reference each other in the same cpp file, but the first one won't recognize objects of the second class type

Tags: c++, class, reference

The compiler gives me: "the variable has incomplete type rotation2d"

```
class translation2d
{
    public:
       double x;
       double y;

        translation2d()
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
        }
    translation2d rotateBy(rotation2d rotation) //issue here
    {
        translation2d copy=*this;
        copy=translation2d(x*rotation.cosM()-y*rotation.sinM(), x*rotation.sinM() + y*rotation.cosM());
        return copy;
    }
};
double kEpsilon = 0.000000009;

class translation2d;
class rotation2d
{

    public:
       double cosAngle;
       double sinAngle;

    public:
        rotation2d() 
        {
            cosAngle=1;
            sinAngle=0;
        }

        rotation2d(translation2d& direction, bool norm)
        {
            cosAngle=direction.x;
            sinAngle=direction.y;
            if(norm)
                normalize();
        }

    double cosM()
    {
        return cosAngle;
    }
    double sinM()
    {
        return sinAngle;
    }
    double tanM()
    {
        if(abs(cosAngle)<kEpsilon)
        {
            if(sinAngle>=0.0)
                return std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
            else
                return -1*std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
        }
        return sinAngle/cosAngle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve circular dependencies in C++, [**forward declarations**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) are invented for.

Somehow OP tried it but in a wrong way.

So, if

- `class translation2d` needs `class rotation2d`

and

- `class rotation2d` needs `class translation2d`

the second one has to be forward declared before the first.

```
struct rotation2d; // forward declaration -> incomplete type

struct translation2d {
  void doSomethingWith(rotation2d rot);
};

struct rotation2d {
  void doSomethingWith(translation2d trans);
};
```

[**Demo on Compiler Explorer**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/wAvQou)

A forward declaration makes an [**incomplete type**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type).
Incomplete types are restricted concerning what can be done with them.

Neither the size nor the contents of an incomplete type is known.
Hence, the compiler denies everything where this would be needed, e.g.

- allocation of storage (i.e. makeing a variable or member variable of it)
- access to contents (i.e. read/write member variables or call member functions).

It is allowed to use incomplete types for

- pointers and references (with any qualification)
- parameters of function declarations.

I must admit that I was not aware of the latter but found:
[SO: Incomplete types as function parameters and return values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47817138/7478597)
for my enlightment.

Please, note that parameters of function **declarations** may be incomplete but not parameters of function **definitions**. Hence, the second part of the fix is to make functions *non-* inline if incomplete types are needed in them.

```
struct rotation2d; // forward declaration -> incomplete type

struct translation2d {
  void doSomethingWith(rotation2d rot);
};

struct rotation2d {
  void doSomethingWith(translation2d trans)
  {
    trans; // will be processed somehow
  }
};

// now both types are complete

void translation2d::doSomethingWith(rotation2d rot)
{
  rot; // will be processed somehow
}
```

[**Demo on Compiler Explorer**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2d9L9V)

---

The fixed and completed sample code of OP:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

class rotation2d; // forward declaration

class translation2d
{
    public:
       double x;
       double y;

        translation2d()
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
        }
        translation2d(double x, double y): x(x), y(y) { }

    translation2d rotateBy(rotation2d rotation); //issue here fixed
};
double kEpsilon = 0.000000009;

class rotation2d
{

    public:
       double cosAngle;
       double sinAngle;

    public:
        rotation2d() 
        {
            cosAngle=1;
            sinAngle=0;
        }

        rotation2d(const translation2d& direction, bool norm)
        {
            cosAngle=direction.x;
            sinAngle=direction.y;
            if(norm)
                normalize();
        }

    double cosM()
    {
        return cosAngle;
    }
    double sinM()
    {
        return sinAngle;
    }
    double tanM()
    {
        if(abs(cosAngle)<kEpsilon)
        {
            if(sinAngle>=0.0)
                return std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
            else
                return -1*std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
        }
        return sinAngle/cosAngle;
    }

    void normalize()
    {
        const double len = std::sqrt(cosAngle * cosAngle + sinAngle * sinAngle);
        cosAngle /= len; sinAngle /= len;
    }
};

// both types complete now -> circular dependency resolved

translation2d translation2d::rotateBy(rotation2d rotation)
{
    translation2d copy=*this;
    copy=translation2d(x*rotation.cosM()-y*rotation.sinM(), x*rotation.sinM() + y*rotation.cosM());
    return copy;
}

int main()
{
    translation2d t(1.0, 2.0);
    rotation2d r(translation2d(0.0, 1.0), false);
    translation2d tR = t.rotateBy(r);
    std::cout << "tR: (" << tR.x << ", " << tR.y << ")\n";
}
```

Output:

```
tR: (-2, 1)
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7512e0a49e317cb4)